# Accessing Web service using Python

Tags: python, webservice-client, suds, zeep

I have been trying to connect to a web service using SUDS and Zeep. Neither of them work and throws different errors.

The server is using a wsHTTP_endpoint and a AXMS_endpoint, I can connect to the later but the endpoint does not provide me with the accurate access so I need the wsHTTP endpoint.

**Working Code for AXMS**:

```
from suds.client import Client
client = Client(wsdl)
x =client.service['AXMS'].Method({'datapoint':23})
```

**What I have tried with SUDS**:

```
from suds.client import Client
client = Client(wsdl)
x =client.service['wsHttp_Endpoint'].Method({'datapoint':23})

Exception: (415, "Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'.")
```

I even tried `client.set_options(headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8'})`

But then I got a bad request error. `Exception: (400, 'Bad Request')`

**What I have tried with Zeep (same code as above with zeep client):**

```
from zeep import Client
from zeep.wsse.username import UsernameToken
client = Client(wsdl)

error: The message could not be processed. This is most likely because the action XXXXX is incorrect or because the message contains an invalid 
or expired security context token or because there is a mismatch between
bindings. The security context token would be invalid if the 
service aborted the channel due to inactivity. 
To prevent the service from aborting idle sessions prematurely increase the Receive timeout on the service endpoint's binding.
```

This give me an error on the binding.

Comment: *"This give me an error"* ...and we are supposed to guess which error you might get?

Comment: Please show us what error it gives.

Comment: The errors are no in the code.